# Comparing two dates in php not working

Tags: php

I have this code to compare:

```
 $dateregister = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($register['date']));
   if ($dateregister < date('d/m/Y')) {
      $class = 'danger';
   } else {
     $class = '';
   }
```

Always enter in if, but some dates (`$dateregister`) are bigger than `date(d/m/Y)`

Comment: [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns a string, so you are actually comparing two strings. Better use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php) class!

Comment: You are doing a plain string comparison. `2/1/1999 > 1/1/2018`. If you really dont want to use DateTime class, then compare by: `date('Ymd')` instead (treats it as an int).

Comment: Thank you, my `dateregister` is in d/m/Y format

Comment: So? You are turning `$register['date']` into a timestamp, and turning it back into a string. And doing a string compare. What exactly is inside `$register['date']` ? Do a [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then compare with today using the class methods.

Comment: 31/01/18 or 310118 is > then 15/12/18 or 151218, with dates you shouldn't be comparing the string values. Just looking for a dupe, its been answered before many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dateRegister = strtotime($register['date']);
if($dateRegister < strtotime(date('d/m/Y'))){
     $class = "danger";
}else{
     $class = "";
}
```

I am sure it will be helpful because `strtotime` returns timestamp and it executes exact comparing operators

Otherwise you should use Date Class and it's easy to get comparison of 2 dates.

```
$today = new DateTime('');
$expireDate = new DateTime($row->expireDate); //from database

if($today->format("Y-m-d") < $expireDate->format("Y-m-d")) { 
   //do something; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but wont work

Comment: I Updated with another possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. but same problem

Comment: For some reason when I put `format("d-m-Y")` wont work, but when I put `format("Y-m-d")` works fine

Comment: Well there is standard of storing date Y-m-d so maybe we need to convert into standard first and then into printable form.